# How do I make basic authentication with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, github-api

In github, there's this section where you can do basic auth... If I was using curl, this would look like:

```
$ curl -u <username>:<token> https://api.github.com/user
```

How do I turn that into http request if I were to do it in angular?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it. I based my answer from [icodeya](http://www.icodeya.com/2015/06/how-to-perforn-basic-authentication-in.html).

```
function authenticateUser(username, authtoken) {

  var url = "https://api.github.com/user"

  var credentials = btoa(username + ':' + authtoken);
  var authorization = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials};
  var header = { headers: authorization }

  return $http.get(url, header)
     .then( function(response) {
        function() { //do something here. }
     }
  );
}
```

Comment: That's the way to do it!  I'm curious about the token you're using, is it a JWT?  And where are you storing it?  I always want to help with front-end security :) if you're building a front-end app, you might find my blog articles useful: 

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/)

[https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)